# How to convert images to string on flutter

Tags: node.js, flutter, dart

So I have this flutter app where the person needs to upload some photos from his gallery on the application. How do I store these images on the application and convert them to string so that it saves into my database? (Mongo DB)

I want to:

1. Save the images into a value
2. Convert this value to string
3. Save the string images into a class 'beneficiary'

[Application UI Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p52XK.png)

```
class BeneficiaryServices extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _beneficiaryState createState() => _beneficiaryState();
}

class _beneficiaryState extends State<BeneficiaryServices>
    with View<BeneficiaryServices> {
  var data;
  bool autoValidate = true;
  bool readOnly = false;
  bool showSegmentedControl = true;
  File _image;
  final picker = ImagePicker();

  beneficiaryservicesController controller =
      new beneficiaryservicesController();
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _fbKey = GlobalKey<FormBuilderState>();

  Future save() async {
    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    setState(() {
      if (pickedFile != null) {
        _image = File(pickedFile.path);
      } else {
        print('No image selected.');
      }
    });

    var res = await http.post(Uri.parse("http://192.168.56.1:8080/signin"),
        headers: <String, String>{
          'Context-Type': 'application/json;charSet=UTF-8'
        },
        body: <String, String>{
      
        });
    print(res.body);
  }

  Beneficiary beneficiary = Beneficiary('', '', '', '');

  @override
  Widget getBody() {
    return Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 200,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: 20.0,
            ),
            
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: _image == null
                  ? Text('Upload Proof of address')
                  : Image.file(_image),
            ),
            FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: getImage,
              tooltip: 'Pick Image',
              child: Icon(Icons.add_a_photo),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: _image == null
                  ? Text('Upload Birth Certificate')
                  : Image.file(_image),
            ),
            FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: getImage,
              tooltip: 'Pick Image',
              child: Icon(Icons.add_a_photo),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: _image == null
                  ? Text('Upload CEB/CWA/Phone Bill')
                  : Image.file(_image),
            ),
            FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: getImage,
              tooltip: 'Pick Image',
              child: Icon(Icons.add_a_photo),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: _image == null
                  ? Text('Upload Proof of Loan (if applicable)')
                  : Image.file(_image),
            ),
            FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: getImage,
              tooltip: 'Pick Image',
              child: Icon(Icons.add_a_photo),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                  ),
                  primary: const Color(0xffde0486),
                ),
                child: Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  child: const Text(
                    'Submit Application',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      package: 'flutter_credit_card',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  print('valid!');
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Controller getController() {
    return this.controller;
  }

  @override
  InstanceNames getName() {
    return InstanceNames.ZakatCalculator;
  }
 void getImage() {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final imageBytes = await pickedFile.readAsBytes();
final base64Image = base64Encode(imageBytes);
```

Where [`base64Encode`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/base64Encode.html) returns a base64 encoded representation, of type `String`, of the provided byte array.

Comment: Hi, can you please tell me where should I put these two lines in my code? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Wherever you need the string representation of your image. Obviously, `pickedFile` refers to the variable of the same name in your `save` method.

Answer (score -1):

You can read the image file path and convert it into a base64 string.

```
 final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    setState(() {
      if (pickedFile != null) {
        _image = File(pickedFile.path);
      } else {
        print('No image selected.');
      }
      final bytes = await pickedFile.readAsBytes();
      print(imageBytes);
      String base64Image = base64Encode(imageBytes);
      print(base64Image);
      .....
      .....
      }
```

Comment: Hi, can you please tell me where should I put these lines in my code? Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is no such variable as `widget.fileData` in the OP's post.